# type '(BuildContext, Widget) => ChangeNotifierProvider<>' is not a subtype of type '(BuildContext, Widget?) => Widget' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

type '(BuildContext, Widget) => ChangeNotifierProvider' is not a subtype of type '(BuildContext, Widget?) => Widget' in type cast

Hi, I am facing above error on my old project while I was converting it to Flutter 2.5, can anyone help me to figure it out?

```
abstract class Role {
  Widget homeBuilder(BuildContext context);
   Map<String, WidgetBuilder>? routes;

  /// The navigatorBuilder allows you to insert widgets between MaterialApp and its Navigator.
  /// This is useful for providing the logged in Talent or Recruiter
   TransitionBuilder? navigatorBuilder;
}




@override
  TransitionBuilder navigatorBuilder =
      (BuildContext context, Widget navigator) {
    String token = Provider.of<AuthBloc>(context).token;
    MyNotifications.setUpFirebaseMessaging(context);
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Talent>(
      create: (ctx) =>
      (Provider.of<AuthBloc>(context).role as TalentRole).talent
        ..setAuthToken(token),
      child: navigator,
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TransitionBuilder:

```
typedef TransitionBuilder = Widget Function(BuildContext context, Widget? child);
```

expects a context and a child. The child is of type `Widget?`, note the question mark. This shows you the widget can be null.

If you define a TransitionBuilder you need to show that too, so you need to change

```dart
@override
  TransitionBuilder navigatorBuilder =
      (BuildContext context, Widget navigator) {
```

to

```dart
@override
  TransitionBuilder navigatorBuilder =
      (BuildContext context, Widget? navigator) { //add the question mark
```

More info on null safety:
https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Comment: Thank you so much! How I forgot this :(  and stuck for 4 hours.